# função recursiva com listas

Tags: python

Preciso escrever uma função recursiva que receba 2 listas e devolva uma nova lista com a subtração dos elementos das primeiras, por exemplo:

```
>>> subtrai([2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3])  
[4, 5]
```

Sei que preciso de saber se um elemento da 1ª lista pertence à 2ª: no caso de pertencer esse elemento não poderá fazer parte do resultado, caso contrário pertence.

O problema está que não posso utilizar a função remove()...

Neste momento tenho o seguinte código

```
elem = []

if elem in l1 and l2:
    return list(l1-l2)
else:
    return l1
```

Este código devolve-me apenas a lista 1, não consigo perceber o que estou a fazer errado

Agradeço desde já a vossa ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Creio que esta implementação irá atender a tua necessidade!

```
def subtrair(list1, list2):
    for i in list2:
        list1.remove(i)
    return list1
```

Comment: Sim, essa implementação seria a solução. Contudo, não posso utilizar a função remove(). É por esse motivo que não estou a conseguir resolver o problema.

Comment: @rguest pode utilizar o del?

Comment: Como o del faz a mesma função que o remove (se não estou em erro, se estiver por favor clarifique-me), calculo que também não pudesse ter usado. Por isso, optei por utilizar o remove de qualquer das formas.

Answer (score 0):

Cara ta meio confuso o que postou, mas a característica da recursão 'e ela chamar a si mesmo. Como eu vi no enunciado voce pode retornar uma terceira list, então utilizei um contador auxiliar e uma list "global", os elementos serão sempre colocados pelo método append na "global". caso o numero exista nas duas listas ele não entra na segunda condição e so chama a si denovo.

PS:Eu estou utilizando python3,e com certeza ha um método melhor que meu, mas também estou começando python espero que ajude.

```
def subtrai(list1,list2,contador):

    if len(list1) >contador:

        if not list1[contador] in list2:

            listaDeRetorno.append(list1[contador])

        contador+=1
        subtrai(list1,list2,contador)

    return listaDeRetorno

def main(): 
    list1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
    list2 = [5,6,7]
    contador=0
    novaLista = subtrai(list1,list2, contador) 
    print("A nova lista 'e",novaLista)

listaDeRetorno=[] 
main()
```